# Can't figure out how to use isAnimationFinished() method (LibGDX)

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I am having some trouble getting my `isAnimationFinished()` finished to work in a program I am working on. Currently, it seems to just always go into this method. Another issue with the animation is that it almost instantly goes through all the sprites where I would like to prolong each frame for about .25 seconds or so. My relevant code is below, any other questions or help would be appreciated!

**Render Call:**

```
public void render(float delta) 
    runTime += delta;
    world.update(delta);
    renderer.render(delta, runTime);
```

**Animation Creation:**

```
TextureRegion[] waterGraphics = { water1, water2, water3 };
waterAnimation = new Animation(0.25f, waterGraphics);
waterAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);
```

**Animation Draw:**

```
if(!waterAnimation.isAnimationFinished(runTime)) {
        //System.out.println("1");
        batcher.draw(waterAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), penguin.getX()+30,
                penguin.getY(), penguin.getWidth() / 2.0f,
                penguin.getHeight() / 2.0f, penguin.getWidth()*5, penguin.getHeight()*5,
                1, 1, penguin.getRotation()); // Don't leave at *5.....
            simpleCounter++;
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this animation class what i am using for my project.To check for finish you can check if last frame is running by `getCurrentFrame()` method.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class Animation {

private Sprite[] frames;
private float time;
private float delay;
private int currentframe;
private int timesplayed;

public Animation(){}

public Animation(TextureRegion[] frames){
    this(frames, 1/12);
}

public Animation(TextureRegion[] frames,float delay){
    this.setFrames(frames, delay);
}

public Animation(Sprite []a,float delay){

    this.frames=a;
    this.delay=delay;
    time=0;
    currentframe=0;
    timesplayed=0;
}

public void setFrames(TextureRegion[] frames,float delay){
    this.frames=new Sprite[frames.length];
    for(int i=0;i<frames.length;i++){
        this.frames[i]=new Sprite(frames[i]);
        this.frames[i].getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear,TextureFilter.Linear);
    }

    this.delay=delay;
    time=0;
    currentframe=0;
    timesplayed=0;

}

public void update(float dt){
    if(delay<=0)return;
    time+=dt;
    while(time >= delay)step();

}

private void step() {
    time-=delay;
    currentframe++;
    if(currentframe==frames.length)
        currentframe=0;
    timesplayed++;
}

public Sprite getFrames() {
    return frames[currentframe];
}



public float getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(float time) {
    this.time = time;
}
public float getDelay() {
    return delay;
}


public void setDelay(float delay) {
    this.delay = delay;
}

public int getCurrentframe() {
    return currentframe;
}

public void setCurrentframe(int currentframe) {
    this.currentframe = currentframe;
}

public int getTimesplayed() {
    return timesplayed;
}

public void setTimesplayed(int timesplayed) {
    this.timesplayed = timesplayed;
}


}
```